# Refresh The Main Page

Tags: discussion, poo-storm

Add a comment if you had Apple.StackExchange.com loaded today and refreshed the page "N" times to see if the new design appeared…

<sub>This is a joke ;)</sub>

**Update for the less humorous out there:**
A bird¹ told me that we should *see* it "VERY soon" [sic].

¹ A rare type of *bird* that likes [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon) a lot.

Comment: Damn you. I though it was Jin telling  us to refresh the page to see the new design :/

Comment: @Loïc It's a TRAP!

Comment: @Martín the cake is a lie!

Comment: POO-STORM!!1!1!1!!

Comment: @calavera excellent tag ;)

Comment: @Martín did you email him?

Comment: @kyle Nope, twitter ;)

Answer (score 4):

YESSSSS!!!!!!! We're live!!!!!

Comment: Now must announce it to other sites :D